# How to compute 'purgeable' disk on APFS volume, on macOS?

Tags: macos, disk, macos-high-sierra, apfs

My application needs to know the free space on a APFS volume.

It seems the operating system can 'reserve' purgeable disk space, starting from macOS High Sierra and APFS.

When using NSFileManager function, it only returns 'real' free space:

```
NSDictionary* pathAttrs = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileSystemAttributesAtPath: path];
    NSNumber* pathSize = pathAttrs[ NSFileSystemSize];
    NSNumber* pathFreeSize = pathAttrs[ NSFileSystemFreeSize];
```

[image]

**My question: how to compute or estimate this 'purgeable' free space?**

Comment: this should be local time machine snapshots, check if it is using the command `tmutil listlocalsnapshotdates` and see if it returns some listing.